# Mi formulario de contacto devuelve el error al enviar

Tags: php, html

Tengo un inconveniente con mi página, estoy seguro que es algo muy simple pero no me estoy dando cuenta donde tengo el error. El problema consiste en que no me funciona el formulario de contacto, me tira el siguiente error:

"Error"

El link de mi página es http://impulsart.com.ar/3237/gs.html

Y acá les adjunto mi código HTML:

```
    <form name="contactform" method="post" action="mail/gs_enviar.php">
<table>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="name">Nombre Y Apellido *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">E-mail *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telefono">Telefono *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telefono" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comunidad">Nombre de la Comunidad *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="comunidad" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="usuario">Usuario del Panel *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="usuario" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="pass">Contraseña del Panel *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="pass" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="juegos">Seleccionar Juego *</label>
  </td> 
  <td valign="top">
          <select name="juegos">
<option>-- Seleccionar --</option>
<option>Counter Strike 1.6 100FPS</option>
<option>Counter Strike 1.6 300FPS</option>
<option>Counter Strike 1.6 500FPS</option>
<option>Counter Strike 1.6 1000FPS</option>
<option>Counter Strike GO - 64TICKRATE</option>
<option>Counter Strike GO - 128TICKRATE</option>
<option>Counter Strike Source - 64TICKRATE</option>
<option>Counter Strike Source - 128TICKRATE</option>
<option>Team Fortress Classic</option>
<option>SAMP</option>
<option>Left 4 Dead</option>
<option>Mu Online</option>
<option>Wow</option>
<option>Minecraft</option>
</select>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="pagos">Formas de Pago *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
<select name="pagos">
<option>-- Seleccionar --</option>
<option>Rapipago</option>
<option>Pago Facil</option>
<option>Transferencia</option>
<option>Bapro</option>
<option>Cuenta Digital</option>
<option>Dinero Mail</option>
</select>
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="branding">Quitar Branding 50$ (By rnkhost.net) *</label>
 </td>
  <td valign="top">
          <select name="branding">
<option>-- Seleccionar --</option>
<option>Si</option>
<option>No</option>
</select>
 </td>
</tr>
<td>
<p> En el mensaje ingresar Server - Cantidad de Slot</p>
            Ejemplo:
            <p> Server 1: 12 slot</p>
            <p> Server 2: 14 slot </p>
            <p> Server 3: 16 slot </p>
            </td>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="message">Mensaje *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="message" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2">
 <br>
 <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfrGS8UAAAAAM1aPxprLtJSdfrOxRa1A5icy_A6"></div>
 <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar"></a>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Y aca les dejo el gs_enviar.php que seria:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // 

    $email_to = "info@impulsart.com.ar";

    $email_subject = "Web - GameServer";

    function died($error) {

        // mensajes de error

        echo "Lo sentimos, hubo un error en sus datos y el formulario no puede ser enviado en este momento. ";

        echo "Detalle de los errores.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Por favor corrija estos errores e inténtelo de nuevo.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // Se valida que los campos del formulairo estén llenos

    if(!isset($_POST['name']) || 
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telefono']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comunidad']) ||
        !isset($_POST['usuario']) ||
        !isset($_POST['pass']) ||
        !isset($_POST['juegos']) ||
        !isset($_POST['pagos']) ||
        !isset($_POST['branding']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {

        died('Lo sentimos pero parece haber un problema con los datos enviados.');

    }
 //En esta parte el valor "name"  sirve para crear las variables que recolectaran la información de cada campo

    $name = $_POST['name']; // requerido

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // requerido 

    $telefono = $_POST['telefono']; // requerido

    $comunidad = $_POST['comunidad']; // requerido

    $usuario = $_POST['usuario']; // requerido

    $pass = $_POST['pass']; // requerido

    $juegos = $_POST['juegos']; // requerido

    $pagos = $_POST['pagos']; // requerido

    $branding = $_POST['branding']; // requerido

    $message = $_POST['message']; // requerido

    $error_message = "";//Linea numero 52;

//En esta parte se verifica que la dirección de correo sea válida 

   $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'La direccion de correo proporcionada no es valida.<br />';

  }

//En esta parte se validan las cadenas de texto

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {

    $error_message .= 'El formato del nombre no es valido<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($message) > 2) {

    $error_message .= 'El formato del texto no es valido.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    die($error_message);

  }

//Este es el cuerpo del mensaje tal y como llegará al correo

    $email_message = "Contenido del Mensaje.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "Nombre: ".clean_string($name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telefono: ".clean_string($telefono)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comunidad: ".clean_string($comunidad)."\n";
 $email_message .= "Usuario: ".clean_string($usuario)."\n";
 $email_message .= "Password: ".clean_string($pass)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Juegos: ".clean_string($juegos)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Pagos: ".clean_string($pagos)."\n";
      $email_message .= "Branding: ".clean_string($branding)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Mensaje: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

//Se crean los encabezados del correo

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

?>



<!-- Mensaje de que fue enviado-->

Gracias! Nos pondremos en contacto contigo a la brevedad

<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Cuento se tiene un código que no funciona, es muy útil crear un [mcve]. Inténtalo y reemplaza el código que has publicado por la versión más breve que produzca el problema.

Comment: Que error te muestra, pudieran intervenir varios factores:
1.- la direccion del archivo php no sea correcta.
2.- algun error de sintaxis

Comment: El error que comentas: _"Error" Verifique todo si falta algo y esta todo bien_  no aparece en el código que has compartido... ¿No tendrás confusión de archivos? De todos modos sugiero que busques otra forma de validar tu formulario, y hacerlo del lado del cliente. Existen muchísimas funciones javascript ya hechas para validar el envío de formularios. Otra opción que puedes explorar y funciona de maravilla son los [formularios de Google](https://www.google.com/intl/es/forms/about/).

Comment: Hola Dario, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor, completa el [tour] para ver como funciona el sitio, y lee [ask] donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tus preguntas y sea más fácil ayudarte a solucionar el problema.

Comment: Perfecto , ya edite bien la pregunta. Cuando lleno el formulario , apreto el boton enviar y me abre una pestaña que dice "Error" por lo que se el error esta en la parte de cuando genero las variables , el nombre de cada uno es el mismo que el .html .

Comment: Borre el mensaje "Error"  ..... Pero sale el msj Gracias! Nos pondremos en contacto contigo a la brevedad , pero no me llega nada va no llega  el msj. Que puede ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente inicializas la variable $error_message con "**Error**"
y luego preguntas si tiene una longitud mayor a cero, lo cual siempre es verdadero, y entonces llamas a *die($error_message)*

```
...

$error_message = "Error ";//Linea numero 52;

...    

if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    die($error_message);
}

...
```

Espero haber ayudado